# Web API Post Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've a `Web API`, where I have five list of cricketers. By using a Web Form I can perform `CRUD` operation. When I'm submitting on Get Cricketers then I able to get all the list of cricketers which I passed in my `controller` as `static`. I make code for post in my Web Form class and want post one cricketer When I click on to PostCricketer button. It is posted successfully but have some issue that Cricketer should not be insert with same rank, in ascending order. Please help The screenshot points are

- After clicking on get cricketers I've successfully get all five cricketers
- The inserted record should be in ascending order Duplicate
- Rank should not be inserted, should be shows a simple label message that Cricketer already exist with this rank.

This is my Controller Code

```
public class CricketersController : ApiController
{
    public static List<Cricketer> cricketers = InitCricketers();
    public IEnumerable<Cricketer> Get()
    {
        return cricketers;
    }
    public Cricketer Get(int id)
    {
        return cricketers.Where(c => c.Rank == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    public void Post(Cricketer cricketer)
    {
        cricketers.Add(cricketer);
    }
    public void Put(Cricketer newCricketer)
    {
        Cricketer cricketer = cricketers.Where(c => c.Rank == newCricketer.Rank).FirstOrDefault();
        cricketers.Remove(cricketer);
        cricketers.Add(newCricketer);
    }
    public void Delete(int rank)
    {
        Cricketer cDel = cricketers.Where(p => p.Rank == rank).FirstOrDefault();
        cricketers.Remove(cDel);
    }
    private static List<Cricketer> InitCricketers()
    {
        List<Cricketer> cricketers = new List<Cricketer>();
        cricketers.Add(new Cricketer
        {
            Rank = 1,
            Name = "A.B. de Villiers",
            Runs = 5000
        });
        cricketers.Add(new Cricketer
        {
            Rank = 2,
            Name = "D.A.Warner",
            Runs = 10000        
        });
        cricketers.Add(new Cricketer
        {
            Rank = 3,
            Name = "ViratKohli",
            Runs = 8480
        });
        cricketers.Add(new Cricketer
        {
            Rank = 4,
            Name = "J.E.Root",
            Runs = 6620
        });
        cricketers.Add(new Cricketer
        {
            Rank = 5,
            Name = "F.duPlessis",
            Runs = 2000
        });
        return cricketers;
    }
```

This is my PostButton Code

```
protected void btnPostCricketer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblCricketerPosted.Text = "";
    int crank = Int32.Parse(txtNewCricketerRank.Text);
    string cName = txtNewCricketerName.Text;
    int cRuns = int.Parse(txtNewCricketerRuns.Text);    
    Cricketer newCricketer = new Cricketer
    {
        Rank = crank,
        Name = cName,
        Runs = cRuns
    };
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(address.ToString(), newCricketer).Result;

    // Check that response was successful or throw exception
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    response.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpResponseMessage>().Wait();
    lblCricketerPosted.Text = "New Crciketer Added!";

    btnGetAllCricketers_Click(sender, e);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is Rank Primary Key ??

Comment: Please provide code to show us your request, as well as a sample response. etc. It would be a good idea to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No, actually no database created in this web api, just an property of the model class that I represented in Controller

Answer (score 0):

The list by itself won't check if the rank value is already added so you need to check the value before adding it to the list.
Also, you should return a response to the requester if the request was successful or not. In this example I just return a [IHttpActionResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.ihttpactionresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(Cricketer cricketer)
{
    if(!cricketer.Any(a=>a.Rank == cricketer.Rank))
    {
        cricketers.Add(cricketer);
        Return Ok("Success");
    }else{
        Return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Rank already exists!"); //You could use a more suitable http code here
    }
}
```

And to get the values in ascending order you could

```
public IEnumerable<Cricketer> Get()
{
    return cricketers.OrderBy(x => x.Rank).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I want this code on button click. Suppose I'm returned a list of cricketers by clicking on to GetCricketers button, next if I want to add two cricketers in (first cricketer with rank 7 then 6) then the order should be ascending.

Comment: @AmitMishra First of, IHttpActionResult works, the question is what error msg you get when you use it?
The OrderBy returns a list in ascending order...

Comment: #Marcus, Any in the above code does't contained a definition for it.

Comment: @AmitMishra Here's the spec for it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.ihttpactionresult(v=vs.118).aspx.
Recommend you to read this article about the usecases https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results